# My Shiba Inu has been diagnosed with Double-Chambered Right Ventricle

Tags: dogs, surgery

My 1 year old Shiba has been diagnosed with Double-Chambered Right Ventricle which is a rare (in dogs) Congenital Heart Disease.

Has anyone dealt with this an been able to successfully operate this deformation ?

I am European citizen living in Asia and looking at surgeons in these two regions of the world preferably.

Does anyone know of a veterinary clinic that would be able to operate this rare condition ?

Any advices regarding paliative care and what we should prevent our pup from doing ?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who finds this, we ended up going with a heart surgery at jasmine clinic in Tokyo.

Can't recommend them enough.

https://jasmine-vet.co.jp/English.html

EDIT: If anybody needs more info, please leave a comment here, and Ill help.